# Creating a MessageBox with multiple Checkboxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox

In a recent project I'm planning to allow the user to make certain configuration using a MessageBox with various CheckBoxes. The number of these CheckBoxes is variable and depending on the amount of entries the User made beforehand, so I don't know how big of a Box I need and how many CheckBoxes there will be inside it.
When the user is done checking and unchecking, he will press the "OK" Button and the values should be returned and saved.

Multiple questions to this whole thing:
1. Is this a good/logical way to approach this whole thing? (Having the user make yes/no configurations to an unknown amount of options)
2. How would I create a MessageBox/Pop-Up with an uncertain amount of CheckBoxes?
3. Is there any smart way to design that box, so that it is not to big or to small and fits every option evenly spaced?

Comment: If you are in win-form then try `FlowLayoutPanel` and add check boxes programmetically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is this a good/logical way to approach this whole thing? (Having the user make yes/no configurations to an unknown amount of options)

Yes, what else could u do if the options to agree with depend on previous settings. So yes this design is ok.

> 2. How would I create a MessageBox/Pop-Up with an uncertain amount of CheckBoxes?

In general, i highly suggest to not use the standard `MessageBox` of the .NET Framework. I would make my own window, and place all in with an yes/no button.

> 3. Is there any smart way to design that box, so that it is not to big or to small and fits every option evenly spaced?

Design ur window based on a `Grid`. Then pick a place that can be ur viewing area. In this place add some kind of stack control ae `StackPanel`. Then just load dynamically ur controls into this stack and ur done.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry, but I'm pretty new to VisualStudio, if I lay down a Grid onto the new Form, how would I do this? Make a grid with same sized Cells over the entire Form?

Comment: I normally do it like on webpages. U put ur grid onto the form, add 3 rows. 1st is the fixed Header, 3rd is the fixed Footer, 2nd is the not fixed view area. the header and footer have fixed height, the view area has it on auto. and the window height is also on auto. Voila ur done.